# How to fetch cloudinary URL data from MongoDb

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, cloudinary

I just succeeded in uploading an image to Cloudinary and saved in my MongoDB database. I have been trying to fetch the saved URL and display it in react, but I haven't succeeded. I always get "{image: undefined}"

here is my Database :

```
id:5f90315331dc1727bc869afe
userEmail:fletcher@gmail.com
image:https://res.cloudinary.com/workaman/image/upload/v1603285/ifyo38crkdniixeimme9.jpg
imageId:ifyo38crkdniixeimme9
```

My get() endpoint :

```
app.get("/getAvatar/:email", (req, res) => {
 
  console.log(userEmail)
  Image.findOne({userEmail:req.params.email},(err, images)=> {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500);
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      res.json(images);
    }
  });
});
```

my display component :

```
 class AllImages extends Component {

state={
image:''
}

    componentDidMount(){
        const { user } = this.props.auth;
        const email = user.email
        axios.get("/getAvatar/"+ email)
    .then(
      (res) => {    
       
        var newState = {
         
          image: res.data.image,
    
        }
        this.setState( newState );
        console.log(newState)
      }, 
      (err) => {
        alert('An error occured! Try refreshing the page.', err);
      }
    );
    console.log(this.state.image)
  }

        
    
    render(){
  
        
        return (
            <div>
                <img
                src={this.state.image}
                
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

My Model :

```
const ImageSchema = new Schema({
 
  image: String,
  imageId: String,
  userEmail:String
});

const Image = mongoose.model("Image", ImageSchema);
module.exports = Image;
```

The output is a blank page, and when I console.log I get {image: undefined}. This is the first time I am working with url in mongodb. I dont know what might be wrong

Comment: What does the response body look like? Open your Network tab in chrome developer tools and see if the response contains a key `image`. From what I can see your response should be an array.

Comment: No, i didn't see the Image key, here is what my response header looks like :    
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0
Last-Modified: Sun, 05 Jan 2020 03:57:39 GMT
Date: Thu, 22 Oct 2020 13:12:39 GMT
ETag: W/"13d-16f73d9ed3a"
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 317
Vary: Accept-Encoding.......or am i suppose to check else where

Comment: The response headers are not of interest. What does the json body look like? You are accessing `res.data.image` but I don't see why the response should contain a key `image`. Shouldn't it be an array?

Comment: You are correct! it should be an array. while I try and work around that new info, can you please help me with a snippet, had be so glad. meanwhile i will try and work on it! thanks